# journalctl stops working randomly after boot on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, packer, journalctl

I am building servers from a custom image I made using Packer on DigitalOcean, and I'm having a recurring issue where journalctl doesn't have any logs:

```
# journalctl
No journal files were found.
```

Sometimes I have this issue with images I build, sometimes I don't. Sometimes one server built from the same image works and another doesn't.

I have also noticed that if I log in really quickly to the server, sometimes journalctl is initially working but breaks soon after (<1 minute later).

If I restart journald then it works as normal from then on, but I lose all the logs prior to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't random. The "randomness" is based on whether 10 minutes have elapsed between building the image, and starting the server – that is why sometimes the same image gives different results.

The issue is that you have not cleared the machine id in the image.

DigitalOcean inject a first-boot script via cloud-init to generate a new machine id if there was one in the base image. The heuristic this script uses to tell if a machine id is baked into the image is to check if the mtime on `/etc/machine-id` is more than 10 minutes ago.

`/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-instance/machine_id.sh`:

```
# record timestamp on machine-id for testing
# If /etc/machine_id is over 10m old on first-boot, delete it
if [ -f /etc/machine-id ]; then
    if [ $DIFF -lt 600 ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
rm -rf /etc/machine-id
fi
```

The systemd journal stores log files on disk in a directory named after the machine-id, so changing the machine id makes it lose track of those logs.

You can see the logs from before the machine id changed by telling `journalctl` to load logs from the old directory, e.g:

```
journalctl -D /var/log/journal/4ff0f6fdda274a6b9d2b9287b8a15c81
```

The fix here is to clear the machine-id in your baked images. You can do this by removing `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` and `/etc/machine-id`, or alternatively you can use the machine-id script from [packer-virt-sysprep](https://github.com/DanHam/packer-virt-sysprep), which is a library of useful scripts for preparing a VM to be an image.